# bootstrap: using .btn with .accordion-toggle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I added the `btn` class to the `accordion-toggle` div of the accordion widget and it seems to work fine. I'm just wondering if this would be considered undefined behaviour and if I should expect to see it break in future releases.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mss9b/)

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed to "not break" when you upgrade, but really this is a question for the developers themselves, and they probably cannot give you a definite answer. You can always patch it yourself if it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.btn` class only really adds visual styles (font size, background color, etc.), so I see no reason why it would break in the future.

That said, why not just reuse the styling from `.btn` and apply it directly to `.accordion-toggle` if you're concerned?